# Add a new column to a dataframe using matching values of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I am trying to fill in table1 with matching val2 values of table2

```
table1$New_val2 = table2[table2$pid==table1$pid,]$val2
```

[image]

But I get the warning

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

which is fair enough because the table lengths are not the same.

Please kindly direct me on the correct way to do this.

Comment: `merge(table1, table2, by="pid")` optionally add in the `all.x=TRUE` argument if desired.

Comment: hi cory, what if there are other columns in table2 but I only wish to add col2?

Comment: `merge(table1, table2[, c("pid", "col2")], by="pid")`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`merge(table1, table2[, c("pid", "val2")], by="pid")`

Add in the `all.x=TRUE` argument in order to keep all of the pids in table1 that don't have matches in table2...

You were on the right track. Here's a way using match...

`table1$val2 <- table2$val2[match(table1$pid, table2$pid)]`

Comment: If the column names aren't the same but they are actually content-wise the same, would I just state their names in by.x and by.y ?

Example: pid in table1 is called just that, but in table2 it has another name, e.g. pidx

Comment: Yup, by.x and by.y are for the case when they index names are different between the two tables.

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if you mean this but you might use:

```
newtable <- merge(table1,table2, by  = "pid")
```

This will create a new table called newtable, with 3 columns and those values matched by the id, in this case "pid".

Answer (score 4):

I'm way late here, but in case anybody else asks the same question: 

 This is exactly what dplyr's inner_merge does.

```
table1.df <- dplyr::inner_join(table1, table2, by=pid)
```

The by-command specifies which column should be used to match the rows.

EDIT: I used to have so much difficulty remembering it's a [join], and not a [merge].

Comment: I prefer this to `merge()` as the table is not shuffled in the process, although the function is now called `dplyr::inner_join()`

Comment: pid also now needs to be in "" - i.e. table1.df <- dplyr::inner_join(table1, table2, by = "pid")