# inserting a column of categories based on other columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, columnsorting

My dataframe currently looks like this:

```
Tree Cookie Age 
C1T1   A     10
C1T1   A     20
C1T1   A     30
C1T1   B     15
C1T1   B     20
C1T1   B     25
C1T2   A     12
C1T2   A     20
C1T2   B     5
C1T2   B     13
```

So for each "Tree" I have several "Cookies", and for each cookie I have different ages (basically representing different parts of the tree's life). I would like to add another column that bins each tree by its max age - the oldest age of the oldest cookie, in this case it would be the last age of cookie A in both trees (so will classify a tree as "young" if the max age is < 40, "mid-age" if max age is > 40 and < 120, and "old" if max age is > 120). Any advice on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here it goes:
I used the `dplyr` library to do this, which gives me the `%>%` operator and the `summarise()` function. I also named your data frame `trees`. Then:

```
library(dplyr)

trees2 <- trees %>%
  group_by(Tree = Tree) %>%
  summarise(Age = max(Age))

trees2$Cat <- ifelse(trees2$Age < 40, "young", ifelse(trees2$Age > 120, "old", "mid-age"))
trees$Category = trees2$Cat[match(trees$Tree, trees2$Tree)]
```

Before, `trees2` would have bee this:

```
> trees2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Tree  Age  
  <chr> <chr>
1 C1T1  30   
2 C1T2  5  
  
> trees2$Cat <- ifelse(trees2$Age < 40, "young", ifelse(trees2$Age > 120, "old", "mid-age"))

> trees2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Tree  Age   Cat  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 C1T1  30    young
2 C1T2  5     old
```

After, using the recommendations in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37034242/r-add-a-new-column-to-a-dataframe-using-matching-values-of-another-dataframe) by cory, I finished by putting this tibble in the original table with this final line:

```
trees$Category = trees2$Cat[match(trees$Tree, trees2$Tree)]
```

And this gave me:

```
> trees
   Tree Cookie Age Category
1  C1T1      A  10    young
2  C1T1      A  20    young
3  C1T1      A  30    young
4  C1T1      B  15    young
5  C1T1      B  20    young
6  C1T1      B  25    young
7  C1T2      A  12      old
8  C1T2      A  20      old
9  C1T2      B   5      old
10 C1T2      B  13      old
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `cut`:

```
trees_max <- trees %>%
  group_by(Tree) %>%
  summarise(max_age = max(Age))

breaks <- c(0, 40, 120, Inf)
labels <- c("young", "mid-age", "old")

trees_max$cat <- cut(trees_max$max_age, breaks, labels)
```

gives you

```
> trees_max
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Tree  max_age cat    
  <chr>   <dbl> <fct>  
1 C1T1       30 young  
2 C1T2       20 young  
3 C1T3       35 young  
4 C1T4       77 mid-age
```