# How to add a column from a df to another df based on other columns?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, join, merge

Hi I have two data frames. One with missing data that I would like to add from the other data frame which has complete data.

This is the first data frame with the complete data.

| ID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 012 | Dave | 45 |
| 013 | Colin | 63 |
| 014 | Dave | 52 |

This is the second database that I would like to join with the first and take the ID from the first using both the name and age column.

| ID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Dave | 45 |
|  | Colin | 63 |
|  | Dave | 52 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - Add a new column to a dataframe using matching values of another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37034242/r-add-a-new-column-to-a-dataframe-using-matching-values-of-another-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Take two datasets:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name=c("Andy", "Henry", "Tom", "Andy", "Martin"),
                  Age =c(55, 46, 32, 38, 61),
                  ID  =c(1:5))


df2 <- data.frame(Name=c("Andy", "Henry", "Tom", "Andy", "Alex"),
                  Age =c(55, 46, 32, 38, 24))
```

Here are four different kinds of merge you can do depending on what you want to do with missing observations:

```
merge(df1, df2, on=c("Name", "Age"))
merge(df1, df2, on=c("Name", "Age"), all.x=TRUE)
merge(df1, df2, on=c("Name", "Age"), all.y=TRUE)
merge(df1, df2, on=c("Name", "Age"), all=TRUE)
```

Alternatively you could use data.table joins:

```
data.table(df1)[data.table(df2), on=c("Name", "Age")]
```

More correctly:

```
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
setkey(df1, "Name", "Age")
setkey(df2, "Name", "Age")
df1[df2]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's one solution to your problem :

```
library(dplyr)

my_df1 <- data.frame("ID" = c("012", "013", "014"),
                 "Name" = c("Dave", "Collin", "Dave"),
                 "Age" = c(45, 63, 52),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_df2 <- data.frame("Name" = c("Dave", "Collin", "Dave"),
                 "Age"= c(45, 63, 52),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


my_df3 <- left_join(my_df2, my_df1, by = c("Name", "Age"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
ID <- c("012", "013", "014")
Name <- c("Dave", "Colin", "Dave")
Age <- c(45, 63, 52)
df1 <- data.frame(ID, Name, Age)
df2 <- data.frame(Name, Age)

newtable <- merge(df1, df2, by  = c("Name", "Age"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

my_df1 <- data.frame("ID" = c("012", "013", "014"),
                 "Name" = c("Dave", "Collin", "Dave"),
                 "Age" = c(45, 63, 52),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_df2 <- data.frame("Name" = c("Dave", "Collin", "Dave"),
                 "Age"= c(45, 63, 52),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You can use `merge()`

```
my_df3 <- merge(df2, df1, by = c("Name", "Age"))
my_df3
```

or you can use `rbind.fill()`to first combine different data frames into one and later delete the missing `NA's`

```
df3<-rbind.fill(df1, df2)
drop_na(df3) #drop NA's



  ID   Name Age
1  012   Dave  45
2  013 Collin  63
3  014   Dave  52
4 <NA>   Dave  45
5 <NA> Collin  63
6 <NA>   Dave  52
```